# Lombok Getter & Setter not working in bean having custom deserializer

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, lombok

The issue is I use Lombok annotations `@Getter` and `@Setter` with beans which are used to parse JSON files.
The issue is I noticed for attribute with custom deserializer, Jackson is not using this custom deserializer and I get error like:

```
For boolean field, only true or false are recognized
```

while I'm receiving `"no"` for `false`, and `"yes"` for `true`.

```java
@JsonProperty(value = "comment")
@JsonDeserialize(using = NoYesDeserializer.class)
private Boolean comment;
```

I put the annotation on the class level : `@Data` and `@NoArgsConstructor`

```java
public class NoYesDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Boolean> {

@Override
public Boolean deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(p.getText())) {
            String text = p.getText();
            if (text.toLowerCase().indexOf("yes") >= 0) {
                return Boolean.TRUE;
            } else if (text.toLowerCase().indexOf("no") >= 0) {
                return Boolean.FALSE;
            }
        }

        throw new IOException("Unrecognized boolean value " + p.getText());
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your `NoYesDeserializer` ?

Comment: @RandallFlagg, thank you for you answer. Please find the deserializer added into my question.

Comment: @RandallFlagg: can you please respond?

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue, but I could't. Can you share you dependencies versions? I'm using `org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.0`, `com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.9.0` and `com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.7`.

Comment: I'm using lombok 1.16.16 Jackson-core   and databind 2.8.8

Comment: Maybe show example of json you're trying to deserialize?

Comment: I think this should not be issue with lombok, because in case it wouldn't see setters it would use reflection to set property.

Comment: In fact the class is used to map a json file coming in a RabbitMQ queue.

Comment: Please share more code. Share a _minimal_ class with you custom-deserialized element, show the JSON for it.